# Slow apigee response on cached items

Tags: caching, apigee

I've setup a responseCache and added a header for cache hits and misses based on the example in github. The responses seem to work as expected where the first call for a specific key returns a miss, but the second returns a hit in the headers. The problem is that there seems to be a lot of latency even on a cache hit. In the 500ms - 1000ms range, which seems really high to me. Is this because it's on a developer account?

I also tried the trace and those responses seem to be quick as expected, like 20 ms, but not in the app from my laptop in chrome.

Here are some details for the 10K request.

[image: Split of latency]
[image: time details]

Compare those times to stackoverflow.com for example (logged in) which is 200ms and 40K for the page data. For fun, I added stackoverflow to the system and enabled the cache and got similar very slow responses.

```
ab -n 100 -c 1 http://frank_zivtech-test.apigee.net/schedule/get?date=12/12/12
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking frank_zivtech-test.apigee.net (be patient).....done


Server Software:        Apache/2.2.16
Server Hostname:        frank_zivtech-test.apigee.net
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /schedule/get?date=12/12/12
Document Length:        45664 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   63.421 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      4640700 bytes
HTML transferred:       4566400 bytes
Requests per second:    1.58 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       634.208 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       634.208 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          71.46 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       36   47  20.8     43     166
Processing:   385  587 105.5    574     922
Waiting:      265  435  80.7    437     754
Total:        428  634 114.6    618    1055

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    618
  66%    624
  75%    630
  80%    652
  90%    801
  95%    884
  98%   1000
  99%   1055
 100%   1055 (longest request)
```

Here it is using webpagetest.org with a different cached endpoint with very little data:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140228_7B_40G/

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be related to a free vs. paid account.

If trace is showing ~20ms for the time spent in Apigee, I would factor in network latency from your client (laptop) to Apigee.  Time between the client and Apigee can also be higher depending on the payload size and if it is compressed (gzip, deflate).

Comment: I'm on a fast cable connection, so that seems to be really high.

Comment: I added more information above. There was 650ms spent "waiting" for a response, which seems to be about average. I don't think that is the network latency. Any other thoughts or ways I could test it further?

Comment: When you use trace in Apigee, is the complete transaction time still showing ~20ms?  From my experience, the time reported in trace is accurate.  Have you tried other tools like apache bench or jmeter to send the requests and capture the response times?  Might want to try sending a 25+ requests to see if the response time starts to decrease.  There can be multiple message processors(MP) for even free accounts. You may be routing to different ones and cache is being populated from the datastore to the MP memory for the first request to that MP.

Comment: requests in trace still say 15 and 20 ms range, but I added the ab test to the top of the page. I'm expecting like 200ms for a cached response and I'm still getting in the 600ms - 1000ms range for most requests as you can see in the ab test above on a warm cache.

Comment: With this info, it's leading me to believe it has to do with a free account -- only because resources are shared with the free offering.  Didn't think there would be differences with paid.  However, now it seems like it could be related to shared network performance with the free infrastructure since trace is showing good processing times.  I've seen the Apigee software in the cloud with dedicated instances (including network resources) perform in the 200ms or less when returning cache and same payload size ~40K.